# Swing GUI not scaling from computer to computer

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I designed (Netbeans Project) the swing GUI in one computer 15" screen.

Next, I moved the project to another computer 14" screen. When I launch the app in the 14" screen, it's like zooming the GUI and I can't see some part of it.

How can I let my design adjust itself from one computer to another?

Ps : In the GUI editor of netbeans, the size is the same in both computers

**Update**
I don't know if layout manage will solve it as they said in comments. I've just notice my Windows 10 displays 125 % zoom scaling on 1920 x 1080 resolution. When I switched to 100%, though all other applications of the computer looked aweful, the design I made in Netbeans looked exactly the same. What can I do then ? I think it's more related to Windows scaling than Swing's LayoutManager features. Am I correct ?

Comment: *"How can I let my design adjust itself from one computer to another?"* Layout managers.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you for your reply. Please see my update in the OP

Comment: @tomjohnes Please provide the full complete source code of an example application as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. It should use a layout manager of your choice (or a combination of layout managers via several `JPanel` objects). After that provide screenshots of the application from your different computer screen sizes and windows zoom settings. Then describe how the design/layout/scaling should look instead based on these information, source codes and screen shots.

Comment: @Progman Forget about it. It's just for a small project. I'll just design the software on the computer which has the lowest specifications. Thank you mate

Comment: @Progman Do you guys know why Netbeans prewing rendering is different from Windows redering ? Netbeans preview gives the EXACT design I made

Answer (score 1):

You need to use layout managers. Layout managers will organize your components in different ways depending on screen size, aspect ratio, etc.

Depending on what kind of GUI you want, you are going to [choose](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) a different layout manager. Once you have picked a layout manager, you can pass it to a JPanel on construction

```java
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
```

More on info on how to use layout managers, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Please see my update in the OP